# Вызов скрипта из случайной папки

Tags: bash

Есть скрипт `script.sh` Он находиться в папке `~/Desktop/scripts/`. Если зайти туда и запустить его через терминал то он работает. Как сделать так чтоб его вызов работал из любой папки? Т.е. если я нахожусь в папке `~/Downloads` и в терминале напишу вызов скрипта `bash script.sh` то он запустился

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo ln -fs /home/username/Desktop/scripts/script.sh /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

Эта команда создаст символьную ссылку, которая позволит запускать скрипт из любого каталога просто по имени: `$ scripts.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Что бы запускать скрипт находясь в другой директории, необходимо писать полный путь до него.

```
bash /~/Desktop/scripts/script.sh
```

Так же можно сделать алиас. Либо добавить директорию со скриптом в $PATH либо сам скрипт туда.

Comment: да мне нужно чтоб его запустили только командой `bash scripts.sh` без ввода пути

Comment: Оно так не работает... В принципе, можно добавить путь в PATH или сделать команду в баше.

Comment: Извините, подправил ответ.

Comment: "либо сам скрипт туда" -  что вы имели ввиду? Куда туда?

Comment: в консоли наберите $PATH - система выдаст вам путь по умолчанию. Туда и киньте. Вот вывод на моей система к примеру: 'bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:'